# Redirecting to a different webpage results in a doctype error

Tags: html, node.js, express

The Error:

`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON (anonymous) @ script.js:56`

So this is my server side code block which is the issue:

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.query;
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM authdetails WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    db.query(sql, [username, password], (err, results) => {
        console.log(results);
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error searching for user:", err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Database error" });
        } else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                res.redirect("/webpages/codingspace/coding.html");
            } else {
                res.json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and this is my client side code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-field");

    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const username = document.getElementById("login-username").value.trim();
        const password = document.getElementById("login-password").value.trim();

        // Send a GET request to check login credentials
        fetch(`/login?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.message === "Login successful") {
                    alert("Login successful");
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid username or password");
                }
                document.getElementById("login-username").value = "";
                document.getElementById("login-password").value = "";
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    });
});
```

I've noticed that the error only pops up when the redirect code is executed:
`res.redirect("/webpages/codingspace/coding.html");`

If instead, I write an alert checking for the login like: `res.json({ message: "Username-PWd pair exists" });`, the alert pops up all well and good.

In a perfect world, I would assume that the redirect to the new page happens without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly redirect browser by redirecting JavaScript/AJAX call from the server.

When making a request with JavaScript/AJAX, `res.redirect` redirects *that* request, and sends the new page content back to the JavaScript, not the browser, so it's actually JavaSript that is being redirected, not the browser (AJAX is meant to change the content without reloading/redirecting, take SPAs, for example). (For comparison, the redirect would work if the request was made via HTML `form`, not via `fetch`, because in that case the browser would be the consumer, making the request).

So, you should instead send back a flag indicating JavaScript to redirect the browser, for example, send `url` back and then redirect the browser to that url via JavaScript:

server:

```
if (results.length > 0) {
    // send res.json in place of res.redirect, and include `url` to redirect to
    res.json({message:"Login successful", url:"/webpages/codingspace/coding.html"});
} else {
    res.json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
}
```

browser:

```
if (data.message === "Login successful") {
    alert("Login successful");
    // redirect to the url if success
    window.location.replace(data.url);
} else {
    alert("Invalid username or password");
}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks mate, that worked!